# Whitelisting Foreign Keys

Tags: cakephp

How are folks generally handling the whitelisting of foreign key values? Let's ignore the use case of an associated `user` record which brings an additional set of issues and stick to a fairly benign scenario: A `Task` belongs to a `Project`. When I create the task, I want to create it with its `project_id` value, but I don't want that value to be editable. The property is passed by a hidden field in the shared form.

I know I could just unset that property in the controller before calling `save()` in the edit action, but I was wondering whether anyone had a better solution. I've used/tried several, but all are laborious or less "universal" than I'd like.

Does anyone have a solution that they really like to solve this particular problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handle this manually as well. The process is something like this.

1. Load object and show the edit screen to the user.
2. When user submits, take the primary ID and load the object again. Check ownership.
3. Have a whitelist of user editable fields, loop through those keys and populate your new object, leave everything else alone.
4. Save.

You could move this into some kind of before save hook or behavior I would say. But this seems the best practice with the RoR feature (we all know what happened in GitHub)

Comment: Yeah. I'm an avid believer in UUIDs and using those mitigates things a bit (since they're not guessable), but certainly the Github issue has me thinking about this more than usual. Thought maybe someone would have an awesome solution that my Google-fu didn't uncover.